# Creating a signal handler to modify the function return address and skip the offending instruction

Tags: pointers, operating-system, stack

**PROBLEM::** I do not know why my code is not working as it should. As stated in the title, this code needs to hit the line causing the segmentation fault, go into the registered signal_handle method, and advance/modify the return address to skip past the offending instruction to the next good line of code.

**MY APPROACH::** Find the offset based on the param (signalno) and the return address on the stack, go to the offset (-3 int or -12 bytes based on my system), and advance the return address by the offending instruction length (0x5).

**MY CODE::**

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*
 * Your goal must be to change the stack frame of caller (main function)
 * such that you get to the line after "r2 = *( (int *) 0 )"
 */
void signal_handle(int signalno) {
    printf("handling segmentation fault!\n");


    int **stack_ptr = (int **)&signalno;
    stack_ptr -= 3; // Adjust this offset based on your stack layout
    *stack_ptr += 0x5; // Assuming the offending instruction is 5 bytes long. Adjust as necessary based on your findings from GDB.
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int r2 = 0;

    /*Register signal handler first*/
    // SIGSEGV --> Signal number for a segmentation fault
    signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handle);

    r2 = *((int *)0); // This will generate segmentation fault
    r2 = r2 + 1 * 30;

    printf("result after handling seg fault %d!\n", r2);

    return 0;
}
```

**This is my stack (found in GDB using "x/20xw $sp") within signal_handle:**

`0xffffbf90:     0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000 0xffffbfa0:     0x00000000      0x56558fd0*      0xffffcdc8      0xf7fc4560 0xffffbfb0:     0x0000000b*      0x00000063      0x00000000      0x0000002b 0xffffbfc0:     0x0000002b      0xf7ffcb80      0xffffce94      0xffffcdc8 0xffffbfd0:     0xffffcdb0      0x56558fd0      0x00000000      0x00000000`
*(bold is what I thought to be signalno [11 is 0x0000000b in hex] and the return address)*

**This is my assembly for the main function containing the segmentation fault:**

```
   0x565561ff <+0>:     lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   0x56556203 <+4>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x56556206 <+7>:     push   -0x4(%ecx)
   0x56556209 <+10>:    push   %ebp
   0x5655620a <+11>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x5655620c <+13>:    push   %ebx
   0x5655620d <+14>:    push   %ecx
   0x5655620e <+15>:    sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x56556211 <+18>:    call   0x565560c0 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
   0x56556216 <+23>:    add    $0x2dba,%ebx
   0x5655621c <+29>:    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x56556223 <+36>:    sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x56556226 <+39>:    lea    -0x2e13(%ebx),%eax
   0x5655622c <+45>:    push   %eax
   0x5655622d <+46>:    push   $0xb
   0x5655622f <+48>:    call   0x56556060 <signal@plt>
   0x56556234 <+53>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x56556237 <+56>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   **0x5655623c <+61>:    mov    (%eax),%eax**
   0x5655623e <+63>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
   **0x56556241 <+66>:    addl   $0x1e,-0xc(%ebp)**
   0x56556245 <+70>:    sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x56556248 <+73>:    push   -0xc(%ebp)
   0x5655624b <+76>:    lea    -0x1fa8(%ebx),%eax
   0x56556251 <+82>:    push   %eax
   0x56556252 <+83>:    call   0x56556050 <printf@plt>
   0x56556257 <+88>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x5655625a <+91>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x5655625f <+96>:    lea    -0x8(%ebp),%esp
   0x56556262 <+99>:    pop    %ecx
   0x56556263 <+100>:   pop    %ebx
   0x56556264 <+101>:   pop    %ebp
   0x56556265 <+102>:   lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
   0x56556268 <+105>:   ret
```

*(bold is what I thought to be the bad instruction, and the next good instruction)*

Based on the offset and bad instruction length, it is either going in an infinite loop because it keeps returning back to teh offending instruction and then back to the signal_handle OR it goes to the signal_handle ONCE and then throws an actual Segmentation Fault.